# Why cannot show debug by ACE_DEBUG?

Tags: c++, ace

ACE_DEBUG declare #include< ace/Task.h > in source header file.I trace debug define by

> ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, "Reader pathSetOpen : %s
>   ",pathSetOpen);

The string variable name "pathSetOpen" for show value still execute programs.But I cannot compile code.
About ACE_DEBUG,It's macro for printing debug message.

Compile error code.

> EnvTest.cpp:353:1: error: unterminated
>   argument list invoking macro
>   "ACE_DEBUG"

Answer (score 2):

You've forgot a closing parenthesis:

```
ACE_DEBUG((LM_ERROR, "Reader pathSetOpen : %s ",pathSetOpen));
```